# WP JSON REST API (Ryan McCue) how to query posts with specific meta data with 'AND' relation?

Tags: plugins, wp-query, json, rest-api

I use Wp_query class to query my posts. 15 posts are in a template fetched on page load and their filtering works fine. 
Infinity scroll fetches for other posts using [JSON restful services](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/). The filter on the server side works fine but I don't know how to transfer the logic from the server to a proper query.

Meta_query array passed to Wp_query on the server:

```
meta_query

  0 =>  array (size=3)
    'key' => string 'homepage' (length=8)
    'value' => string 'false' (length=5)
    'compare' => string 'NOT EXISTS' (length=10)
  1 => array (size=2)
    'key' => string '_newsml_id' (length=10)
    'compare' => string 'NOT EXISTS' (length=10)
  'relation' => string 'AND' (length=3)
```

How to translate that into the query?
something like:

/wp-json/posts?filter[meta_query][key]=homepage,_newsml_id&[meta_query][compare]=NOTEXISTS

or

/wp-json/posts?filter[meta_query][key]=homepage&filter[meta_query][key]=_newsml_id&[meta_query][compare]=NOTEXISTS

Answer (score 9):

Sorry for answering my own question but it may help some other devs too.

I created this additional filter 'json_query_var-meta_query'that returns the necessary arguments.

```
function adjustQrry($data){
    $args = array();
    $args['relation'] = 'AND';

    foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
        if ( 'relation' === $key ) {
            $args['relation'] = $data['relation'];
        }
        if (  substr($key, 0, 3) === 'key' ) {
            $arg_num = substr($key, 3);
            $args[(int)$arg_num]['key'] = $value;
        }
        if (  substr($key, 0, 7) === 'compare' ) {
            $arg_num_comp = substr($key, 7);
            $args[(int)$arg_num_comp]['compare'] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter('json_query_var-meta_query', 'adjustQrry', 10, 1);
```

Now, I can call JSON restful like that to mimic the Wp_query posts filter already on the server:

```
?filter[meta_query][key]=_newsml_categories_newsstream&filter[meta_query][key2]=homepage&filter[meta_query][relation]=AND&filter[meta_query][compare]=NOT%20EXISTS&filter[meta_query][compare2]=NOT%20EXISTS
```

Ref:
https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/337

Comment: No need to apologize for answering your own question, that's something you *should* do if you're able :)

Comment: As @IanDunn points out, answering your own question is definitely a good thing. You can accept your own answer too, so that others know you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

what about WP REST API V2?
I think this is not working on v2!

```
add_filter('json_query_var-meta_query', 'adjustQrry', 10, 1);
```

should it be like this?

```
add_filter('rest_query_vars-meta_query', 'adjustQrry', 10, 1);
```

Comment: I think, you shouldn't create a new question as an answer, but as a new question. Anyway, I think this would work: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2452

Comment: @websupporter thank you. yeah that is my question too :) you helped much. thanks again.