# Show popular post in another php website via WP REST JSON API

Tags: json, plugin-json-api, popular-posts, web-services, wp-api

I need to show popular & recent posts in another PHP web site under the same domain.

Example:

1. `www.example.com` -> main website (php, mysql)
2. `www.example.com/blog` -> WordPress blog

Need to show popular, recent posts of blog in the main website.

Please note that blog and main website use two separate database.

I decided to use the [WP REST JSON API](http://wp-api.org/) plugin for that. Now I have different question.

I use following code to retrieve last week popular post. What I actually need is to get this same data via API call.

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array( array( 'after' => '1 week ago' ) ),  
    'posts_per_page' => $recent_posts_count,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$popularposts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This has been asked plenty of times. Please use search.

Comment: 1. If you have a new question please open a new question. In this case it might be okay as it isn't totally new. Anyway the title is misleading now. 2. You've seen the documentation: http://wp-api.org/

Comment: I have updated the title as well, however I will go through the doc, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will give you a small answer to your update, doing this with the [WP API](http://wp-api.org/).
The API have the possibilities to use the WP_Query like also in core, but about the get parameters in the url.

A URL to pull content from Post Status would look like this:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/posts
```

To pull content with WP_Query parameters you’re used to, you could do it like this:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=2&filter[order]=ASC
```

You can build your custom query with all parameters also in the url. You can see how the method for grabbing that data feels familiar to using `WP_Query` for a standard WordPress loop. If you don’t specify a parameter, the defaults to `WP_Query` will be used.

The result is json, that you can parse and use for you external site.

See also the [site of the API](http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-posts) for more parameters and documentation.

### Update for `date_query`

The API can't create a result for a query like `query_date`. See the [documentation](http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-posts) for all possible parameters.

But the new version will release in view days, weeks. And see this [issue](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/389) for discussion about a solution for this date query. Alternative use a custom filter via hook, like:

```
// Allow datequery in /posts filter
add_filter( "json_query_vars", function( $query_args ) {
    return array_merge( $query_args, 
        array( "date_query" => array( array( "after" => "1 week ago" ) ) )
    );
} );
```

### Update for `meta_query`

The API can't also this feature of the default WP-Query. But you can use a hook to enhance the API to this requirement. Also here a small example.

```
add_filter('json_query_var-meta_query', 'add_meta_query', 10, 1);

function add_meta_query( $data ){

    $args = array();
    $args['relation'] = 'AND';

    foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
        if ( 'relation' === $key ) {
            $args['relation'] = $data['relation'];
        }

        if ( substr($key, 0, 3) === 'key' ) {
            $arg_num = substr( $key, 3 );
            $args[ (int) $arg_num ][ 'key' ] = $value;
        }

        if (  substr( $key, 0, 7 ) === 'compare' ) {
            $arg_num_comp = substr( $key, 7 );
            $args[ (int) $arg_num_comp ][ 'compare' ] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Now, I can call JSON restful like that to mimic the Wp_query posts filter already on the server:

```
?filter[meta_query][key]=_newsml_categories_newsstream&filter[meta_query][key2]=homepage&filter[meta_query][relation]=AND&filter[meta_query][compare]=NOT%20EXISTS&filter[meta_query][compare2]=NOT%20EXISTS
```

The meta query update based from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169408/wp-json-rest-api-ryan-mccue-how-to-query-posts-with-specific-meta-data-with-a).

Comment: Do you have any idea how to convert the line `'date_query' => array( array( 'after' => '1 week ago' ) ), ` as a query string

Comment: I would like to accept the this as an answer, however if you have any idea regarding the above comment, you can share your thoughts.

Comment: filters other than `filter[posts_per_page]=2&filter[order]=ASC` this two is not working, so it is always giving recent posts only

Comment: @JanithChinthana I have tested again, the filter param works fine. - As Example `http://localhost/wpbeta/plugins/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=1&filter[order]=ASC`. Much more in my update below in the answer.

Comment: thanks for the update, yes `post_per_page` & `order` is working, but what about `meta_key` . does it work with this or I need to extra work for that?

Comment: The `meta_key` is not possible via parameters in the URL. Also like my example for the date query. But you find a usable source solution in this answer (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/169408/170) here on WPSE.

Comment: The now also the update in the answer with a example.